# How to design synchronisation algorithm to combine two automata?

Tags: algorithms, automata, synchronization

I have two automata of states, transition and events (*Etat, Transition, evenements*) and I want to create a function that create the synchronized product between those two automata. For instance, given plant and spec automata, plant :

```
donnees=("nomprob", # name of the problem
        [("e1",True),("e2",True),("e3",True),("s1",False),("s2",False),("s3",False)], # events
        ("plant",[("S4",True,False),("S1",False,False),("S2",False,True)], # first automata (spec) states
            [("S4","S1",["e1","e2","e3"]),("S1","S2",["e1","e3"]),("S1","S4",["s1","s2","s3"]),("S2","S1",["s1","s2","s3"])]), # first automata (spec) transitions
        ("spec",[("S0",True,False),("S1",False,False),("S2",False,True)], #second automata (plant) states
            [("S0","S1",["e1","e2","e3"]),("S1","S2",["e1","e2","e3"]),("S1","S0",["s1","s2","s3"]),("S2","S1",["s1","s2","s3"])] # second automata (plant)transitions
        )
    )
```

I want to have, if it is correct :

[image]

I thought to do

```
for (Etat_s, Etat_p) in plant, spec:
    we create a new state Etat_{s.name,p.name}
    for (transition_s, transition_p) in Etat_s, Etat_p:
        new state with the concatenation of the names of the ends of the transitions
        if transitions' events are the same:
            we add a transition from Etat_{s.name,p.name} to this last state
        else if transition's are different
            here I don't know
```

Added to the issues I have in the algorithm above, I'm sure I would create too many states.

**Merge of finite automata** : I don't have issues with the merged language $L_1||L_2$ as it seems it is the same events. So let $M1 = (Q_1, Σ, δ_1, q_{01}, F_1)$ and $M2 = (Q_2, Σ, δ_2, q_{02}, F_2)$ be two finite automata with the same input alphabet. We define a finite automaton $M_{||}$ such that $L(M_{||}) = L(M1)||L(M2)$ as follows:

$$M_{||} = (Q, Σ, δ_{||}, q0, F∩)$$

where

- $Q = Q1 × Q2$,
- $δ_{||}((q_1, q_2), a) = {(δ1(q_1, a), q_2),(q_1, δ_2(q_2, a))}$,
- $q_0 = (q_{01}, q_{02})$,
- $(q1, q2) \in F\bigcap$ iff $q_1 ∈ F_1$ and $q_2 ∈ F_2$.

By the way, this is part of a project, where the code has been written in French, sorry for that, but which you can find [here](https://github.com/antoinecomp/automata_synchronization).

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by "synchronized product"? Have you read about Cartesian product of automata?

Comment: @Apass.Jack I'm not sure, I just want to merge the automaton and I thought about _synchronizing_ them. But I am agnostic about the method used for it.

Comment: Let me see if I get "merge the automata and synchronize" correctly. You want to run two DFAs at the same time, each given a copy of the same input string. The input is accepted if and only if both DFAs accept it.

Comment: Yes, so we can get the array/graph standing for them when merged. Another example can be [this pdf, especially with example 14th](http://users.abo.fi/jboling/cdes/op_on_aut.pdf). With the definition of the product above.

Comment: @Apass.Jack like a supervisor of those two automata, let say

Comment: "$δ_{||}((q_1, q_2), a) = {(δ1(q_1, a), q_2),(q_1, δ_2(q_2, a))}$. You meant a NDFA, didn't you? If yes, these two DFA are not synchronized at all. It is more like random relay.  Each input character will be handled by one of the DFAs randomly.

Comment: @Apass.Jack, I think I'm wrong then. I rather think it is deterministic as I can't have an infinite number of states given the data I'm providing above

Comment: I cannot understand what is going on here since your DFA is abstract. Can you make each state and transition meaningful? From the semantics in real situations, I might be able to understand what you are driving at.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Yes, states in a given automata look like `("S4",True,False)` : name, isInitial, isFinal. Transitions : `("S4","S1",["e1","e2","e3"])` which stands for nameFrom, nameTo, events leading to the first states to the second one. Is it clearer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87319/discussion-between-thepassenger-and-apass-jack).

Comment: Sorry, I am in the middle of writing something else. I might come back sometime later.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I wonder if my graph is even right or wrong